# Find executable filenames without path

Tags: find

I have a folder with many executables, and I want to omit the path in the results of the find command.
this command shows the files I want to see, but it also lists the path; I just want the file name.

```
find /opt/g09 -maxdepth 1 -executable
```

how can I get the output of find to show only the filenames, and not the full path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or use:

```
find /opt/g09 -maxdepth 1 -executable -printf "%f\n"
```

adding the `-type f` flag also works here.

From the `find` manual:

```
 %f     File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).
```

This answer only requires that you have GNU `find` whereas others require other programs to manipulate your results.

Comment: -type f Thats what i was trying to think of! Thank you coding man!

Comment: @j0h not a problem!

Answer (score 6):

Use `basename` :

```
find /opt/g09 -maxdepth 1 -executable -exec basename {} \;
```

From `man basename`:

```
Print NAME with any leading directory components removed.
```

Also you are trying to `find` everything, to restrict your search to only files, use:

```
find /opt/g09 -type f -maxdepth 1 -executable -exec basename {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious solution to me is

```
(cd /opt/g09; find -maxdepth 1 -executable)
```

Because you start a subshell you remain in the same directory. Advantage of this method is that you don't need parsing. Disadvantage is that you start a subshell (you are not going to feel that though).

Comment: It's a clever idea.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, splitting the path by the delimiter `/`, print the last section (`$NF`):

```
find /opt/g09 -maxdepth 1 -executable | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Where's your python version bro ? ;)

Comment: @Serg haha, I had to tie my fingers :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `find` and `perl`

```
find /opt/g09 -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable | perl -pe 's/.+\/(.*)$/\1/'
```

Comment: Great way to learn some Perl :P